# javascript return null or None if parameter is not given to function

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and this is my function:

```
var now = any(function(result){
    console.log(result);

})


function any(gone){
    return gone
}

console.log(now)
```

but if I give it params like `var now = any(function(result){` it returns me tada.. what I want is it should take default value `null` or `None` like in python and if the value is not provide it should give `null` or `None`

`function any(gone=null)` somthing like this.. after that I want to receive callback in `result`

Comment: function any(gone){
    return gone();
}

Comment: "now" is a function instead of the return value of that function

Comment: What is the expected result? What should be logged, which value should `now` get?

Comment: Prior to ECMAScript 2015 you must test the value of parameters and assign values based on the outcome, see [*MDN: Default parameters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters)

Comment: Please state clearly the problem you are trying to solve, or the desired behavior you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
function any(gone){

   gone = gone || null;

}
```

And in [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) you can do

```
function any(gone = whatever){

       gone = gone || null;

}
```

Comment: doing `null` it gives me `[Function]` as response

Comment: Though you might want a more explicit test like `if (typeof gone == 'undefined')` since `any(0)` or `any(false)` likely should not replace the value with *null*.